# Why aren't inherited properties available in subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to use a member variable called value in a subclass.

My super class is called SType and my subclass is called SResource.

I have a variable in the super class SType called `value`

I want this to be inherited by the subclass, how do I do this. The class looks like this

```
public class SType {

    private String value;

    public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I edited the question to make it more clear (given the comment below). Thanks it was a simple solution, just had to make the variable `protected` rather than `private

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the question. Could you edit your question to provide the parent class, the child class and a short piece of code demonstrating what you want to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access a superclass variable in a subclass, it has to be declared public or protected in the super class.
Maybe yours is private?

When you had `private String value` in the child class - this is a completely new variable - it's not the one from the parent class i.e. you have two distinct private variables (I am assuming the superclass one is private).

Answer (score 2):

You can - make it protected instead of private.

Answer (score 1):

instead of private try:

```
protected String value;
```

b.cos private can only access current class only.
while projected can access sub class

your question is appropriate but the meaning of private in the java meance to protect current variable or method from outside of the class.